# How to stop set interval when a certain condition has been met in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this countdown timer logics, I am using useEffect to set the initial state depending on the incoming props from a parent component, then when the user clicks on an icon the set Time function gets triggered starting the countdown any idea how to set the conditional for it to stop ?
the function ran once and I cannot set the conditional form the setInterval it self ?

```js
//incoming Rest props  30 60 90 sec / 1,2,3,4,5 min 

// When the comopnent gets renderd 
 useEffect(() => {
 const check = rest.includes('Sec');
    if (check) {
      let secs = parseFloat(rest.slice(0, 2));
      setTimer({ ...timer, minutes: secs === 90 ? 1 : 0, seconds: secs === 90 ? 30 : secs });
    }
 }

 // State 
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState<{ minutes: number; seconds: number }>({ minutes: 0, seconds: 0 });
  
 // On click 
 const setTime = () => {
    setInterval(() => setTimer((prevState) => ({...prevState, 
      minutes: prevState.minutes, seconds: prevState.seconds - 1 })), 1000);
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the first, Use `useEffect` only once and **`store` interval state**.

You can stop it  by `clearInterval` and `return null` in your `setState`

```js
const [timer, setTimer] = useState(YOUR_DATETIME_VALUE);
const [loop, setLoop] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        setTimer(new Date(timer.getTime() - timer.getMilliseconds()));

        setLoop(setInterval( () => {
            setTimer(new Date(timer.getTime() - 1000));
        }, 1000));
    }, timer.getMilliseconds());
}, []);

const stopHandler = () => {
    setLoop(interval => {
        clearInterval(interval);
        return null;
    });
}
```

**Notice: use `stopHandler` if you want to stop it**

```
if (Math.abs(new Date().getTime() - timer.getTime) < 1000) {
    stopHandler();
}
```

**Notice: The millisecond difference is calculated in `setTimeout`**

Comment: under what condition the stopHandler is getting trigged ?

Comment: @Richardson Updated